# Edit userdisp.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, user-information-list

I need to **hide some fields** on *userdisp.aspx* form on a SharePoint Foundation 2013. It is known that modifying forms under template/layouts folder is not recommended/supported.

Is there any way to achieve this modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the list settings and go to advanced.  Set allow the management of content types to yes.  Once you have done this, the content type will be available in the list settings.  Click on the content type (the item content type is for custom list by default).  Select the item you want to hide.  It will give you three options to choose from Required, Optional, or Hidden.  Select hidden.

You can do this when you first create the list if you know you are going to be hiding columns.  If you allow content type management, when you make a new column, it will ask you in the bottom of the form if you want to add it to the content type.  If you say no, it will be hidden from the list forms.